# char array in c equal to one letter

Tags: c

I have a char array and im trying to set it equal to a single letter. What's the problem?

```
char letter_grade[1];
if(grades >= 90)
  letter_grade = 'A';
else if(grades >= 80)
  letter_grade = 'B';
else if(grades >= 70)
  letter_grade = 'C';
else if(grades >= 60)
  letter_grade = 'D';
else if(grades < 60)
  letter_grade = 'F';
```

Comment: A look-up table could do this a lot more easily.

Comment: Also why `char letter_grade[1]` instead of `char letter_grade`? If you need just one character you should save it in a single `char`. For a character *string* you'll need a minimum of 2 characters to accommodate the NUL terminator, and you'll also need to use `strcpy()` to populate it.

Comment: @D Doe What C compiler are you using?

Comment: It's C; character arrays and characters are different things--you can't assign one to the other. You can put characters *into* a character array.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `letter_grade[0]` instead of just `letter_grade` while assigning value, example:

`letter_grade[0] = 'A';`

Comment: @P__J__There is a difference between correct and appropriate - code will compile without any error and work as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
char letter_grade[1];
```

to be:

```
char letter_grade;
```

You are trying to declare a Char like an array.